# How to ORDER a list where the same value doesn't appear twice in a row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm returning a list of results from a database but because of a design feature I need a specific order.

The results should return randomly. The only criteria is that one of the values should not appear twice in a row.

Here's the example data:

| id | animals | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hamster | brown |
| 2 | dog | brown |
| 3 | horse | white |
| 4 | mouse | gray |
| 5 | cat | black |
| 6 | bird | orange |
| 7 | snake | green |
| 8 | monkey | orange |
| 9 | chameleon | green |

So I have a list of `animals` and their individual `colours` in the table. I want to return a list of 5 of these animals randomly ordered but without two `colours` show up in a row. So the dog can't show up after the mouse and the chameleon can't show up after the snake etc...

I have solved this with PHP in the past. But I'm looking for a faster and smarter solution and hopefully in MySQL only.

Let me know :-)

Comment: but the colours of `dog` and `mouse` are different ...

Comment: there's an easy solution using LAG, but it has a subtle bias problem; if the first random animal is brown and you reject a second random brown animal, the third animal then has a slightly less chance of being brown than it would if you just rejected an entire set of 5 and restarted until you got a complete set of 5 that obeys the rule.

Comment: What to do if the random set of five hasn't enough diversity? In the extreme case, what if there are only animals of one color?

Comment: Tag the version on MySQL you're using.

Comment: There are two "browns" in the "color" **column**.  Please change the title if you meant **column** instead of **row**.

Comment: @RickJames "in a row" means "consecutively "

Comment: Do you want "hamster" or "dog" when you see "brown"?  Or maybe both -- using `GROUP_CONCAT()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you're using a recent version of MySQL (8.0+), you can do something like this.

The first CTE term provides the data.  You can replace that with any list of data you wish, directly from some table or the result of a complex query expression.

`rn0` is the order of the randomly ordered data.

@Zakaria is correct.  Here's the adjusted SQL to handle just the requirement that consecutive rows should not have the same color, after randomly ordering the data.

Basically, this randomly orders the data and then takes just the first edge of each color island, and limits the result to 5 islands.

```
WITH data (id,animals,color) AS (
        SELECT 1 AS id, 'hamster' AS animals  , 'brown' AS color  UNION
        SELECT 2, 'dog'       , 'brown'  UNION
        SELECT 3, 'horse'     , 'white'  UNION
        SELECT 4, 'mouse'     , 'gray'   UNION
        SELECT 5, 'cat'       , 'black'  UNION
        SELECT 6, 'bird'      , 'orange' UNION
        SELECT 7, 'snake'     , 'green'  UNION
        SELECT 8, 'monkey'    , 'orange' UNION
        SELECT 9, 'chameleon' , 'green'
     )
   , list1 AS (
        SELECT id, animals, color, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rand()) AS rn0 FROM data
     )
   , list AS (
        SELECT *, CASE WHEN color = LAG(color) OVER (ORDER BY rn0) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS good
          FROM list1
     )
SELECT *
  FROM list
 WHERE good = 1
 ORDER BY rn0
 LIMIT 5
;
```

An example result:

```
+----+-----------+--------+-----+------+
| id | animals   | color  | rn0 | good |
+----+-----------+--------+-----+------+
|  9 | chameleon | green  |   1 |    1 |
|  2 | dog       | brown  |   3 |    1 |
|  6 | bird      | orange |   4 |    1 |
|  1 | hamster   | brown  |   5 |    1 |
|  3 | horse     | white  |   6 |    1 |
+----+-----------+--------+-----+------+
```

The original SQL, which does more than requested, requiring distinct colors in the result.  It's not what was requested.

```
WITH data (id,animals,color) AS (
        SELECT 1, 'hamster'   , 'brown'  UNION
        SELECT 2, 'dog'       , 'brown'  UNION
        SELECT 3, 'horse'     , 'white'  UNION
        SELECT 4, 'mouse'     , 'gray'   UNION
        SELECT 5, 'cat'       , 'black'  UNION
        SELECT 6, 'bird'      , 'orange' UNION
        SELECT 7, 'snake'     , 'green'  UNION
        SELECT 8, 'monkey'    , 'orange' UNION
        SELECT 9, 'chameleon' , 'green'
     )
   , list AS (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rand()) AS rn0 FROM data
     )
   , step1 AS (
        SELECT list.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY color ORDER BY rn0) AS rn
          FROM list
     )
SELECT *
  FROM step1
 WHERE rn = 1
 ORDER BY rn0
 LIMIT 5
;
```

Sample result:

```
+----+---------+--------+-----+----+
| id | animals | color  | rn0 | rn |
+----+---------+--------+-----+----+
|  7 | snake   | green  |   1 |  1 |
|  6 | bird    | orange |   2 |  1 |
|  3 | horse   | white  |   3 |  1 |
|  1 | hamster | brown  |   5 |  1 |
|  5 | cat     | black  |   6 |  1 |
+----+---------+--------+-----+----+
```

Comment: That only gets distinct colours. It's not exactly what op wants.

Comment: @Zakaria Good catch.  Might need recursion for that. Actually, edges logic would be sufficient, after the random work.

Comment: @Zakaria I believe the adjusted SQL addresses just the non-consecutive color requirement.

Comment: it works better, but there might be some situations where the query returns less than 5 rows (somewhat unlikely though).

Comment: @Zakaria True.  We might need to retry in unusual or just unlucky cases to generate enough edges.  With at least 5 colors in the data set, that can't happen, however.

Comment: @JonArmstrong thank you for the well-described answer. I understand it and it could be my solution. The downsite of this is the preparing of the "data" of animals within the query. I would love a more dynamic way, so if I add another animal-row, I would not have to define a new row in this query? E.g. I'm adding | 10 | penguin | black | and then I would expect it to show up in the query results immediately? Is that possible?

Comment: @SimonDegn The inclusion of the data within the query is just one way to inject the data.  If you have a table containing the data or a query which produced that data, you can refer to that table directly or include your query within this SQL.  For instance, remove the first CTE term and within `list1` replace `FROM data` with `FROM yourtable`, etc.

Comment: @SimonDegn Notice my comment within the answer: `The first CTE term provides the data. You can replace that with any list of data you wish, <<< directly from some table >>> or the result of a complex query expression.`

Comment: My bad, I didn't read that, sorry. I will try your query now :-)

Comment: @JonArmstrong it works like a charm! Perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this?

```sql
select any_value(name), color from animals group by color order by rand() limit 5;
```

Fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ff1854c9698e2c60deaf9131ea87774c

Comment: That's a functional dependence / `GROUP BY` mistake and is only allowed if MySQL is configured to ignore that error.  Try that with MySQL 5.7 or better, which has the proper GROUP BY behavior.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=83bcc15e120a71a4c644c1f6d1025140

Comment: All right, edited

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' your solution groups the animals in colours and only show one of each. It's correct that this could solve my problem, but I am more curious to find a solution where it's not all different colours but the same color just doesn't appear twice in a row.